# como llamar un metodo de una clase a un metodo de otra clase

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipse

La cuestión es la siguiente, tengo que calcular el perímetro de un triángulo pero necesito llamar el  método `calcularDistancia` de `class Punto` a `class Triangulo` en el método `calcularPerimetro` o en términos simples meter un método dentro de otro método.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Punto {

private int x;
private int y;


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "X=" + x +"\n"
           +"Y=" + y + "";
}


public Punto(int x, int y) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}


public int getX() {
    return x;
}


public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void mostrar() {
    System.out.println(this.toString());
}

public double calcularDistancia(Punto pb) {
    double dis=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-pb.getX(),2))
            +Math.pow(y-pb.getX(),2);
    return dis;
}





public class Triangulo {

private Punto puntoAX,pAY;
private Punto  puntoBX,pBY;
private Punto puntoCX,pCY;

public Triangulo(int puntoAX, int pAY, int puntoBX, int pBY, int puntoC, int pCY) {
    super();
    this.puntoAX = new Punto(puntoAX,pAY);
    this.puntoBX =new Punto(puntoBX,pBY);
    this.puntoCX = new Punto(puntoC,pCY);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Estado del tirangulo\n "
            +"\nPunto A\n"+
            puntoAX+
            "\nPunto B\n"+
            puntoBX+
            "\nPunto C\n"+
            puntoCX
            ;
}

public void mostrarEstado() {
    System.out.println(this.toString());
    System.out.println();
}

public double calcularPerimetro() {
    return 0;


}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no te entendí mal, para llamar la función `calcularDistancia` de `Punto` desde cualquier método de la clase `Triangulo` bastaría con instanciar un objeto de tipo `Punto`

Por ejemplo;

```
public double calcularPerimetro() {
    Punto punto = new Punto(2,3);
    double aux = punto.calcularDistancia(punto);
    //Aquí ya se podrías trabajar tranquilamente con el retorno de calcularDistancia
    return aux;
}
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad, saludos

Comment: gracias me sirvio para completar un requerimiento del taller, si no es mucho problema me podria ayudar ahora con esta otra duda, el problema es el mismo, llamar el metodo calcularDistancia de la class Punto al metodo calcularPerimetro de la class Triangulo pero ahora con un extra, los valores no los da uno si no la class Main, estos valores ahora serian de tipo coordenada cartesiana

Comment: public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Triangulo trianguloA = new Triangulo(10,10,20,30,15,10);
  Triangulo trianguloB = new Triangulo(15,15,23,30,50,25);
  trianguloA.mostrarEstado();
  trianguloB.mostrarEstado();
  
  System.out.println("el perimetro de T1 es "+trianguloA.calcularPerimetro());
  System.out.println("el perimetro de T2 es "+trianguloB.calcularPerimetro());
  
 }

}

Comment: @juanito la solución es la misma, lo único que deberías hacer, es en la función `calcularPerimetro()` recibir un parámetro de tipo `Punto`; osea, osea, pasaría a ser `public double calcularPerimetro(Punto punto)`, ahora, en lugar de instanciar el punto, le pasarías este punto que recibiste, me explico?

Comment: podria ser pero le digo que no, ya que para que el trabajo me lo evaluen el metodo calcularPerimetro() no debe tener ningun parametro, esta es la condicion del trabajo,       calcularPerimetro - este método calcula el perímetro del triángulo y lo retorna.  Este método no imprime nada.  Dentro de este método, debes llamar el método calcularDistancia de la clase Punto.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que tu clase Punto contiene un método para calcular la distancia hasta otra (o la misma) instancia de Punto, es decir, la distancia entre un punto dado y  otro cualquiera,  de esto entonces pues, en el método calcularPerimetro de tu clase Triangulo, al tener ya las instancias de los puntos entonces no tienes que hacer más que sumar las distancias entre cada uno de ellos, sería algo así si no me equivoco:

```java
public double calcularPerimetro() {
    return this.puntoAX.calcularDistancia(this.puntoBX)
    + this.puntoBX.calcularDistancia(this.puntoCX)
    + this.puntoCX.calcularDistancia(this.puntoAX);
}
```

Comment: pues creo que si podria ser pero por alguna razon no me dan los resultados que necesito, por ejemplo al calcular el  perimetro del triangulo1 en calculadora me de 47,97 pero en el programa me suelta en consola un resultado que si no me equivoco de mas de 220

Comment: Debe ser algo relacionado a los valores que le has asignado o bien a la formula utilizada dentro del método de cálculo de la distancia.

Comment: de hecho ese metodo que usted hizo estaba bien la cuestion era que yo tenia mal el codigo, la formula de distancia que yo tenia solo recibia X por lo que los valores de Y no contaban y por eso no me daba el resultado correcto. gracias

Answer (score -3):

No conozco la forma de hacerlo en java, pero en .net funciona de la siguiente manera, depronto te puedas guiar y encontar una forma parecida en java.

public int suma(int a){
  return a+4;
}
public int LlamarMetodo(fun Metodoentrada){
 int resultado = MetodoEntrada(4);
 return resultado;
}

cuando llames el método LlamarMetodo el resultado será 8. Espero que te sirva de algo, por lo pronto buscaré una forma en java y te comento.

Comment: Intenta no dar respuestas referenciando con código escrito en otro lenguaje, ya que pueden ser confusas para la persona que esta teniendo el problema!

Comment: Vale, Solo quería ayudar

Comment: Esta perfecto! lo único que te recomiendo es que no uses ejemplos en otros lenguajes de programación